# Unable to transfer ETH from contract wallet to main account

Tags: wallet-transfer

I have installed Mist 0.9.3 on Linux. 
I have a main account with 0 ETH and a contract wallet with 0.21 ETH.
I am in full sync.

I try to transfer ETH from the contract wallet to the main account in Mist: the 'transfer' window shows the icon for my main account (with 0 ETH) but displays: My wallet: 0.21 ETH.
when I try to transfer, I get 'insufficient funds for gas * price + value, probably because it's trying to draw from the main account, which has 0 ETH.

How can I transfer the ether from my contract wallet to my main account?
I've tried on myetherwallet, but that only imports the keystore for my main account, which has 0 ETH. I think I'd need to import from the contract wallet first - so back to square one.

This is similar to [Can't send from wallet contract to main account with Ethereum Wallet 0.9.0](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24892/cant-send-from-wallet-contract-to-main-account-with-ethereum-wallet-0-9-0) - but with version 0.9.3

I'd try on Windows but I am not sure how to import my contract wallet there. I will soon run out of space with this full sync mode, but I do not think the light (beta version would work better).

Answer (score 1):

In order to interact with contracts on the Ethereum network, you need gas to pay. Transactions also can't be made from contracts, only by private/public key pairs. So the account you're using to interact with your contract wallet needs to have Ether in it in order to interact with the contract wallet, hence why you're getting the "insufficient funds for gas * price + value" error.